# Naturally Ordered Semigroup: Why does axioms imply order of group is infinite countable ? Why are every group equal up to isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, semigroups

Naturally Ordered Semigroup:

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Naturally_Ordered_Semigroup

I know $\mathbb N$ is a naturally ordered semigroup by definition. Also I know that the naturally ordered semigroup is unique up to isomorphism:

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Natural_Numbers_form_Naturally_Ordered_Semigroup

Questions:

Why does the axioms of the naturally ordered semigroup imply that the order of the group is infinite countable (isomorphic to $\mathbb N$) ?

Why can't a uncountable set be a naturally ordered semigroup ?

Could someone explain why every naturally ordered semigroup is equal up to isomorphism (the proof is quite tricky and the notation is hard to understand)

Thanks everyone.

Comment: As for the first question, the cancellation axioms mean that if you multiply everything by some semigroup element, you get back an isomorphic ordering; everything is just shifted. But if you shift a limit ordinal, what replaces it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what a limit ordinal is.

Comment: In well-ordered sets, you can have the regular ordering on the integers, but if you get any bigger than that, you start getting "limit ordinals" which don't have any number before them. So it would be like 1,2,3,...,$\omega$, $\omega+1$, etc. where there's nothing right before $\omega$, it's just a limit of the numbers before it. So the semigroup shifts everything to the right by some amount, but this leaves gaps at the limit ordinals because there's nothing right `below' them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informally speaking, the well-ordering combined with ability to go "exactly one step backwards" (i.e. "subtract one") implies that the countability of the structure; and the properties of naturally ordered semigroup imply this.

In a more formal setting (and possibly not in the most efficient demonstration), let $(S,\circ,\preceq)$ be a naturally ordered semigroup. Then:

1. We can make a simple observation which is not valid for general ordered semigroups, but which becomes true once we have the cancellation property of naturally ordered ones: If $a\prec b$, then $(a\circ c)\prec (b\circ c)$ for any $a,b,c\in S$, where $x \prec y$ means $x \preceq y \wedge x\not=y$ (i.e. being strictly smaller).
2. The well-ordering property tells us that there is some element $\bar{0} \in S$ which is smaller than all the other elements. As the label suggests, it behaves just like *zero* in natural numbers; $\bar{0}\circ x=x$ for any $x$ in the semigroup.

   In order to see why, consider the "subtraction" property of naturally ordered semigroups: It tells us that since $\bar{0}\preceq\bar{0}$, we have $\bar{0}=\bar{0}+z$ for some $z\in S$. By the definition of $\bar{0}$, we have $\bar{0}\preceq z$. If the inequality was strict; i.e. if we had $\bar{0}\prec z$, we'd also have $\bar{0}+\bar{0} \prec \bar{0}+z = \bar{0}$, an impossibility. Thus, $\bar{0}+\bar{0}=\bar{0}$.

   Finally, for any $x\in S$, we have $\bar{0}+x = \bar{0}+\bar{0}+x$ and cancellation simplifies this to $x = \bar{0}+x$.
3. Since $S$ has at least two different elements, the set of elements differing from $\bar{0}$ is non-empty and the well-ordering gives us its smallest element, $\bar{1}$, which is strictly greater than $\bar{0}$, but smaller than all the other elements. Not very surprisingly, it behaves similarly to number *one* among naturals; being the building block to build (all) the remaining ones.
4. Let's define $p_0=\bar{0}$ and $p_{i+1}=p_i\circ\bar{1}$; so that $p_1=\bar{1}$, $p_2=(\bar{1}\circ\bar{1})$ and so on. Since $\bar{0}\prec \bar{1}$, easy induction can be used to prove that $p_i\prec p_j$ whenever $i<j$. Thus, the mapping $i\mapsto p_i$ is actually an isomorphism between the ordered semigroups $(\mathbb{N},+,\leq)$ and $(\{p_0,p_1,\ldots\},\circ,\preceq)$.
5. So far so good; but what about elements of $S$ which are *not* of the form $p_i$ for any natural number $i$? Well, if there are any, the set of all such *strange* elements is non-empty and thus, using the well-ordering property one more time, it has the smallest element which we will call $s$.

   We have $\bar{1}\preceq s$, so according to the naturally ordered semigroup properties, $s$ can be expressed as $s=1\circ t$ for some $t$. Since $\bar{0}\prec \bar{1}$, we have $t=\bar{0}\circ t\prec \bar{1}\circ t=s$. But this means that $t$ must be equal to $p_i$ for some $i$, since $s$ was the smallest non-expressible element. But then, $s=1\circ p_i=p_{i+1}$ and $s$ would be expressible too, contradicting its choice as a non-expressible!
6. All in all, we've shown that the mapping $i\mapsto p_i$ is an isomorphism between $(\mathbb{N},+,\leq)$ and $(S,\circ,\preceq)$. Since being an isomorphism is both symmetric and transitive, it implies that all naturally ordered semigroups are isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N},+,\leq)$ and thus they all must be countably infinite too.

Comment: Thanks alot Peter, very detailed and helpful !